# Why is JSON.parse causing problems in an async unit test, but not in the console?

Tags: javascript, json, unit-testing, async-await

**Context**

I'm trying to test as I work through the serverless-stack examples, and am currently unit testing the create.js file given [here](https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/add-a-create-note-api.html).

**Problem**

It's currently a simple test without assertions, but when it hits `JSON.parse(event.body)` it throws `Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0`.

**create.test.js**

```
import * as create from '../create.js';

test('create', async () => {
  const event = JSON.stringify({'body': 'event'}); // alternatively '{ "body": "test" }';
  const context = 'context';
  const callback = (error, response) => {
    expect(response.statusCode).toEqual(200);
  };

  await create.main(event, context, callback);
});
```

**create.js**

```
import * as uuid from "uuid";
import AWS from "aws-sdk";

const dynamoDb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

export async function main(event, context) {
  // Request body is passed in as a JSON encoded string in 'event.body'
  const data = JSON.parse(event.body);

  const params = {
    TableName: process.env.tableName,
    Item: {
      // The attributes of the item to be created
      userId: "123", // The id of the author
      noteId: uuid.v1(), // A unique uuid
      content: data.content, // Parsed from request body
      attachment: data.attachment, // Parsed from request body
      createdAt: Date.now(), // Current Unix timestamp
    },
  };

  try {
    await dynamoDb.put(params).promise();

    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify(params.Item),
    };
  } catch (e) {
    return {
      statusCode: 500,
      body: JSON.stringify({ error: e.message }),
    };
  }
}
```

I have tried removing JSON.parse, which works, and I've tried running `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({'body': 'event'}))` in the console, which also works.

**Question**

How can I fix my test so that `JSON.parse(event.body)` will not throw an error?

Comment: "JSON.parse(event.body)" event is string it has no body property according to your example

Comment: The problem was the formatting of the JSON. `event` should be {body: '{"content": "etc"}'};

Answer (score 1):

That error is normally seen when the value given to `JSON.parse` is actually `undefined`. So, I would check the code that is trying to parse this - most likely you are not parsing. It might also be "undefined" as a string instead of the literal undefined.